# Flex: vmode=opaque

Tags: apache-flex, firefox

I'm using http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/ for showing html in an flex application. To set this up I need to set vmode=opaque. But doing this messes with keyboardinput (at least a swedish charlayout) in Firefox. For example a press on the array key resolves in two arrow chars/steps. If I remove vmode=opaque it works again.

Comment: you mean wmode right? you have a typo on your question. you wrote vmode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have historically been [lots of issues](http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/?p=164) with setting wmode to opaque. I've had similar issues in the past and had to resort to removing this wmode setting. However, if you're so inclined you could hackishly detect the presence of two keyboard input events within a relatively short time period and suppress one of them. It's not a really elegant solution but if you cannot get rid of wmode, it might be a viable workaround until the bug is fixed by adobe.